# how to get rotation handles for object below other object(s)

Tags: inkscape, selections, rotate

The Inkscape tutorial (found under menu Help -> Tutorials -> Inkscape: Basic) says that in order to get the rotation handles of an object, I need to click it twice:

[image]

Later it says that I can get objects below other objects by using Alt+click, and that I can still drag them by using Alt+drag:

[image]

But it does not say how to get the rotation handles of an object that is below another object. A click does not work since it select the topmost object, Alt+click does not work either because it selects another object below.

**Is there a way to get the rotation handles of an object that is completely below other objects?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select your object under the top one using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> in order to get rotation/skew handles.