Switch selection tool mode for a lower object
Imagine I have 2 identical objects (e.g. squares) in the same place (inserted copy at original position). By clicking, I can only select the topmost object. However, by using the layers, I can select the lower object.
Now, with the lower object selected, how would I switch from size mode to rotate mode?


Related to this question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155781/how-to-get-rotation-handles-for-object-below-other-objects/155782

Pressing Shift + S toggles between handle types in select mode.
You can find more hotkeys here.

I didn't even know that these were called "handles". Thanks.
